# Find number of characters trapped in a list

Tags: python, performance, list, matrix, processing-efficiency

My requirement here is to find number of '0' trapped between 'X' in a list most efficiently.

If you run the below code in Python:

```
def answer(heights):

    row = len(heights)
    col = max(heights)

    matrix = [['X' for j in range(i)] for i in heights]

    for i in range(col):

        rainWater = []

        for j in range(row):

            try:

                rainWater.append(matrix[j][i])

            except IndexError:

                rainWater.append('0')

        print rainWater

    return matrix

answer([1, 6, 5, 3, 2, 10, 4, 2, 6])
```

Output:

```
['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['0', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['0', 'X', 'X', 'X', '0', 'X', 'X', '0', 'X']
['0', 'X', 'X', '0', '0', 'X', 'X', '0', 'X']
['0', 'X', 'X', '0', '0', 'X', '0', '0', 'X']
['0', 'X', '0', '0', '0', 'X', '0', '0', 'X']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'X', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'X', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'X', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'X', '0', '0', '0']
```

I need to find 'O' trapped between two 'X' most efficiently in Python. For example

```
['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']  
['0', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['0', 'X', 'X', 'X', '0', 'X', 'X', '0', 'X']   --> 2 '0' are trapped
['0', 'X', 'X', '0', '0', 'X', 'X', '0', 'X']   --> 3 '0' are trapped
['0', 'X', 'X', '0', '0', 'X', '0', '0', 'X']   --> 4 '0' are trapped
```

Could anyone help me here how to solve this problem in Python?

Comment: Seems very useful. Thank you

Comment: Do you want the trapped elements only side-ways?

Comment: Yes atleast for now but the method has to very efficient since with simple loops I can also do that, but looking for some other method.

Comment: Ah, whoops, I removed the comment with just [the link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill); but I re-read your question, and it doesn't seem flood fill is what you want.

Comment: For now? What do you actually want? :)

Comment: I am just reading this article :D

Comment: Number of trapped elements 'O' between two 'X' in a list.

Comment: Do you want those lists, or are you only creating them so you can get the number of `0`'s between two `X`'s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach would be much simpler. Just count number of zeros within each row stripping out all the 0s at either end

**Implementation**

```
[''.join(row).strip('0').count('0') for row in matrix]
```

**Output**

```
>>> matrix = [['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'],
          ['0', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'],
          ['0', 'X', 'X', 'X', '0', 'X', 'X', '0', 'X'],
          ['0', 'X', 'X', '0', '0', 'X', 'X', '0', 'X'],
          ['0', 'X', 'X', '0', '0', 'X', '0', '0', 'X']] 
>>> [''.join(row).strip('0').count('0') for row in matrix]
[0, 0, 2, 3, 4]
```

This is based on the logic that, if there exist any Zeros within any of the rows, and it is not at either end, that should be enclosed by 'X'.

Comment: Accepted your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could convert each row to a string and then apply a regular expression to find enclosed `0` characters <sup>1</sup>:

```
import re

matrix = [['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'],
          ['0', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'],
          ['0', 'X', 'X', 'X', '0', 'X', 'X', '0', 'X'],
          ['0', 'X', 'X', '0', '0', 'X', 'X', '0', 'X'],
          ['0', 'X', 'X', '0', '0', 'X', '0', '0', 'X']]

pattern = re.compile(r'(?=X(0+)X)')
for row in matrix:
    print len(''.join(pattern.findall(''.join(row))))
```

**Output**

```
0
0
2
3
4
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> I have used `0` (zero) here as per your question. But perhaps it should be `O` (upper case `o`)?</sub>

Comment: I bet OP wanted to do some multidimensional array loops and stuff. but using regex is pretty clever

Comment: regex seems to be an overkill for this problem.

Comment: @Abhijit: it does now that you have posted your solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
matrix = [['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'],
      ['0', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'],
      ['0', 'X', 'X', 'X', '0', 'X', 'X', '0', 'X'],
      ['0', 'X', 'X', '0', '0', 'X', 'X', '0', 'X'],
      ['0', 'X', 'X', '0', '0', 'X', '0', '0', 'X']]

[each[1:-1].count('0') for each in matrix]
```

Comment: I made a try with slicing. You can even use this :)

Comment: What if a row contains all zeros?

Comment: @mhawke Thanks for pointing it
Using check  'X' in each will avoid it. Still I am seeing some scenario skips. Either restructuring matrix **list(re.findall('X.*X',''.join(each))[0])**  will do. But I don't think that is efficient too.

Comment: There are 2 working answers already posted. The accepted one is very simple and elegant. The other (mine) is a working reg ex solution. I'm not sure what you hope to add with another (non-working) reg ex solution.